# Retain Liberty sessions during Bluemix Active Deploy

Tags: session, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, jsessionid, active-deploy

When I use the active deploy service to upgrade my Liberty app to a new version, existing user's sessions are lost and they are logged out.

Is it possible to automatically hand over the session data to the new staging app instance from the old instance, so that sessions are not lost? If not, what alternatives do I have? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Session Cache service on Bluemix does exactly this. Session Cache is a caching service that stores and persists HTTP session objects to a remote data grid.

If you bind it to a liberty application, the Liberty build pack automatically instruments the server.xml with all the right settings to persist the HTTP session objects.

This also works when the application instances scale up and down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It should work, and another option to use use our own DB to persist the session. However we decided to implement our own authentication mechanism (JWT-based) and make the liberty session-less.